# Counterexamples to complex function theory results for Banach space valued functions

Tags: analysis

I'm wondering what results of complex function theory still hold true when considering analytic functions mapping from the complex plane to some complex Banach space. For instance, it can be shown that if f is analytic on a connected open set, and ||f|| has a local maximum then ||f|| is constant. When the image space is the complex field, one can also show that the function itself has to be constant. Does that still hold for Banach space valued functions? And how about the open mapping theorem?

Comment: Read this: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m511/analytic.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it need not be constant.

Consider the Banach space $\mathbb C^2$ with $\|(z_1, z_2)\| = \max(|z_1|, |z_2|)$ and $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^2$  defined by $f(z) = (z, 1)$.  Then $\|f(z)\| = 1$ for $|z| \le 1$.

The open mapping theorem certainly does not hold if the codomain has dimension $> 1$: no open subset of such a space can be homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb C$.

EDIT:   Suppose $f: D \to X$ where $X$ is a strictly convex Banach space, where $\|f\|$ has a local max at $p \in D$.  There is a linear functional $\phi \in X^*$ such that $\|\phi\|=1$ and $\phi(f(p)) = \|f(p)\|$.  By strict convexity, $f(p)$ is the only $v$ with $\|v\| = \|f(p)\|$ and $\phi(v) = \|f(p)\|$.  Thus the analytic function $\phi \circ f$ has a strict local max at $p$, which is impossible.

In particular, this includes the case of a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thanks! Very simple, indeed :-) Any chance for a counterexample with a function mapping into a Hilbert space?